# Monitoring latency statistics with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, metrics, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a job which I am interested in tracking the latency of with Prometheus, with source values like this:

```
timestamp | latency
-------------------
0         | 15ms
1         | 20ms
2         | 18ms
5         | 22ms
6         | 30ms
8         | 5ms
```

Currently I use a CloudWatch Insights query to get some statistics for this latency data. For example, for the above data, I can calculate the min, max, average, and standard deviations over the last 5 minutes:

```
| stats avg(interval), stddev(interval), min(interval), max(interval) by bin(5m)
```

And this gives me a nice little graph like this:
[image: cloudwatch]

In Prometheus, currently I am using 2 counters:

- duration_seconds_total
- duration_count_total

Which allows me to calculate the average latency over 5 minutes:

```
rate(duration_seconds_total[5m]) / rate(duration_count_total[5m])
```

But what about max, min, standard deviation?

I know I could do this with a Gauge and `max/avg/min_over_time` but this would lose fidelity if I'm getting requests more often than my scrape interval.

Is the correct approach here to use a Histogram / Summary? Median then would be roughly p50 (assuming good bucket choices) but how would I calculate min, max, or standard deviation? Is this possible using Prometheus?